# Google Charts, Is it possible to simulate hovering over a legend item with a custom legend?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm creating a custom legend for my charts, but I'd like to retain the ability to highlight part of the chart when I hover over a legend item. I know there is setSelection() but is there some kind of setHover() function?

Comment: no but seems like you could `setSelection` on `mouseover` and remove it on `mouseout`

Comment: setSelection() toggles the tooltip and highlights the chart differently than hover. This is unfortunate. All they need to do is expose the function that they are already using for their hovers.